# Login with Python using requests

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

I'm trying to do a login with Python and after that navigate inside my profile.

I'm trying to make a simple post with 2 params using `requests` and I have this right now:

```
 import requests

 payload = {
    "username": "adminuser",
    "password": "user_pass"
 }

 session_requests = requests.session()

 login_url = 'https://midomain.com/cas/service/portal/login'
 session_requests.get(login_url)

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data=payload
 )

 print result.cookies

 result = session_requests.get('https://www.midomain.com/my-profile', result.cookies)
 print result.url
```

I don't understand why the post method returns a 200 code but after that I can't navigate into my profile (I get a redirection from the web).

Some idea about this performance of my script?

Comment: What if you call it this way: `result = session_requests.get('https://www.midomain.com/my-profile')`?

Comment: What if you `import json` and `data=json.dumps(payload)`?

Comment: Have you verified the login token is actually present in `result.cookies`?

Comment: I have tried with json.dumps, but I get the same result.  @jDo, and Tom Dalton, I going to check the cookies but I´m very sure that I did it. I going to change the method to check if its ok.

Comment: Don't you need to do `cookies=result.cookies`?

Comment: Have you tried with `from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth` as stated [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)?